# Not able to complete post with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with my hospital project with java spring and angular.

When I try to insert a new **Doctor**(*Medico.java*) in a **Hospital** (called *StrutturaSanitaria.java*)
with a **@OneToOne Relationship** mapping a customed relation class, called **MedicoStrutturaSanitaria.java.**  This class is created because I needed an extra column which is **dataAssunzione** (*hireDate*).

As long as I add just the Doctor the Post request works just fine, it adds the instance of the Doctor in the database (*I'm using MySql*).

**THE PROBLEM IS**: When I try to add the relation instance to the DB for every value, except for the hireDate, it gives me null value.
I'm testing the post requests with Postman.

**here is the code**

**Medico.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medico")
public class Medico
{
@Id
private String codiceFiscale;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String cognome;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String genere;

@Column(nullable = false)
private LocalDate dataNascita;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email_uno;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String cellulare_uno;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String indirizzo;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String citta;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String provincia;

@OneToOne
private MedicoStrutturaSanitaria medicoStrutturaSanitaria;

public Medico()
{}

public Medico(String codiceFiscale, String nome, String cognome, String genere,
              LocalDate dataNascita, String email_uno, String cellulare_uno,
              String indirizzo, String citta, String provincia, MedicoStrutturaSanitaria medicoStrutturaSanitaria)
{
    this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cognome = cognome;
    this.genere = genere;
    this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
    this.email_uno = email_uno;
    this.cellulare_uno = cellulare_uno;
    this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
    this.citta = citta;
    this.provincia = provincia;
    this.medicoStrutturaSanitaria = medicoStrutturaSanitaria;
}
//getters and setters
```

**MedicoStrutturaSanitaria.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medico_struttura_sanitaria")
@IdClass(MedicoStrutturaSanitariaID.class)
public class MedicoStrutturaSanitaria
{
@Id
@JoinColumn(name="medico",referencedColumnName = "codiceFiscale")
@ManyToOne
private Medico medico;

@Id
@JoinColumn(name="struttura_sanitaria", referencedColumnName = "codice")
@ManyToOne
private StrutturaSanitaria strutturaSanitaria;

@Id
private LocalDate dataAssunzione;

public MedicoStrutturaSanitaria()
{}

public MedicoStrutturaSanitaria(Medico medico, StrutturaSanitaria strutturaSanitaria, LocalDate dataAssunzione)
{
    this.medico = medico;
    this.strutturaSanitaria = strutturaSanitaria;
    this.dataAssunzione = dataAssunzione;
}
//getters and setters
```

**Postman request. The object passed as parameters are existing instances**
[image]

**Post request method. As you can see all the parameters thar are passed are null, excpet for hireDate**
[image]

**UPDATE 1**
*THIS IS MY CONTROLLER*

```
  @PostMapping("/inserisci-medico-struttura-sanitaria")
public ResponseEntity<MedicoStrutturaSanitaria> inserisciMedicoStrutturaSanitaria(@RequestBody MedicoStrutturaSanitaria medicoStrutturaSanitaria)
{
    System.out.println("Inserendo medico struttura");
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Inserendo medico");
        this.medicoStrutturaSanitariaRepository.save(medicoStrutturaSanitaria);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(medicoStrutturaSanitaria);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Include your controller (2) as code.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I've just updated my question. Added the code of my controller

Answer (score 0):

Before saving relation between doctors and Hospitals. Check if that hospital and Doctor exist in Database or not.(If doesn't not exists create a new one).

If not recommend to send the object of Joining table over the Post request.

Instead 1ts send a two get requests(Get Doctors and Hospitals).
Send one post request(addDoctorInHospital) with doctor_id and hostipal_id and date with provided by the server.

Comment: The doctors and the hospital exist!

Comment: Then send only their ids for mapping.